# Find and Replace performance issue

Tags: ms-access

Table 1: linked native access table
Table 2: linked pgsql table

Both tables have same records but searching for a record using built-in Find and Replace dialog box in selected field is a lot lot slower on Table 2 (linked) with 30K+ records.

Q: Is there any settings or tricks that can be done to improve performance using native Find and Replace functionality? Thanks.

Comment: Placing indexes on required columns (where search is possible) on pgsql would be helpful. But overall it will be slow as compare to local (msaccess) tables.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. The basic Find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) functions in the Access UI search the resultset of the form row-by-row.

For an ODBC linked table (any ODBC linked table, not just PostgreSQL) once Access has gone past the end of the rows that it pre-fetched when it displayed the form it retrieves *one row at a time* until it finds a match or reaches the end.

(Find and Replace is often considerably faster for Access linked tables - as opposed to ODBC linked tables - because the Access Database Engine works directly with the database file, retrieving 4KB pages of data at a time. If consecutive rows happen to be on the same page, or if the 4KB page for a given row has recently been cached, then Access can "get" that row without another round-trip to the database file.)

However, there is one workaround that may be helpful: If a [Filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/apply-a-filter-to-view-select-records-in-an-access-database-HA010341691.aspx) has been applied to a Form or Datasheet view then Find and Replace operations are restricted to the filtered rows. Access can take advantage of indexes and (at least *some*) server-side processing when applying a Filter to a form bound to an ODBC linked table, so you might be able to get the job done faster by Filtering the records first (even a non-[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) filter such as `LIKE "*foo*"`), and then performing the Find and Replace on the filtered set.